# changing the colour of quiz navigation buttons in review

Tags: php, moodle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kqo4.png)I'm using Moodle 3.5 and I hope that someone can help me out in something I'm trying to do:

When a student reviews a graded quiz, the quiz navigation 'block' which appears on the left has a certain default colour coding. Please see the attached image

The question numbers appear inside coloured squares, and:

1) If a student has answered a question correctly, then the square corresponding to that question number appears green.

2) In all other cases, the square  appears red.

Instead of the above two-colour scheme,  I wish to implement the following three-colour scheme in the quiz navigation 'block' of the review:

1) for correctly answered questions, the square should be green ( this is what happens, currently)

2) If a question has been answered incorrectly, the square should appear red (this too is the current default behaviour).

3) if a question has not been answered, the square should appear amber (or any colour except red and green).

I am using the Academi Moodle theme.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRfcd.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? any code you may be able to post.. this doesn't seem like a problem rather an assignment for everybody on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Academy theme allows custom css, so you may be able to apply styles without having to edit theme source code files.

1. In the `admin/settings.php?section=themesettingacademi` page (Administration->Themes->Academi) find the custom css textarea.
2. Post css (change yellow to the color of your choice):

`.path-mod-quiz #mod_quiz_navblock .qnbutton.notanswered .trafficlight {
   background-color: yellow !important;
}`

3. Save changes

Comment: its working, but there is one problem, In Quiz Questions have Negative Marking and i have one option I DON'T WANT TO ATTEMPT THIS QUESTION which have none mark If student Select this option I want to show same color as not attempted